# HTTP response contains text I don't understand

Tags: php, http, post, httpresponse, putty

I have a PHP script that receives a file and returns a response.

The PHP script returns the response like this:

```
echo "<response><status>success</status><message>file received: test.txt</message></response>";
```

When I make the POST request from PuTTY, the response I receive is this:

```
6b
<response><status>success</status><message>file received: test.txt</message></response>
```

Depending on the response, the `6b` could be something else as well? Is this the length of the response in hex, or something else?

The PHP script. Currently, I'm working on simply being able to POST a file and receive and parse the response, hence the PHP file is barebones.

```
<?php  
  if (array_key_exists('file',$_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['size'] != 0)
  {
    $status = 'success';
    $message = "File received: " . $_FILES['file']['name']; 
  }
  else
  {
    $status = 'failed';
    $message = "No file received.";
  }

  $reply = "<response>"
            ."<status>" . $status . "</status>"
            ."<message>" . $message . "</message>"
            ."</response>";

    echo $reply;
?>
```

I am establishing a RAW connection over port 80 on putty, and making the POST request like this:

```
POST /file_post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 212
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8ce9826eb81af6a

-----------------------8ce9826eb81af6a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
TestData
-----------------------8ce9826eb81af6a--
```

Reponse received

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what the `6b` is, but your character length (87d) is 57h.

Comment: How are you retrieving the response in PHP?  If through curl, use CURLOPT_HEADER to see the header as well as the body response.  Does it match what you get in PuTTy?

Comment: The source code of the PHP script would be useful here. If it *is* in fact the length of the message in hex ([here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) is a calculator that will help you check) you are probably looking at [chunked transfer-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: What do you mean by `POST request from PuTTY`? Are you telneting to port 80 on your server and typing request manually?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Yes, that is what I'm doing

Comment: @DaveRandom: posted PHP source code

Comment: Is that BOM chars? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @Márcio I wondered that, but the OP says `Depending on the response, the 6b could be something else as well?`, and if it was a BOM you would expect it to be the same every time.

Comment: @xbonez can you add the full response that you get, including headers? and FYI, there should be an extra line break in your request between `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and `TestData`

Comment: @DaveRandom: I followed up the link on chucked transfer-encoding, and it indeed is the chunk size. Would you want to post that as an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: @xbonez If you have found the answer yourself, even with help, you should answer your own question and accept you own answer, IMHO. I'm not rep hungry enough, I guess...

Comment: @DaveRandom: also, attached screenshot of full response. It does specify `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Chunked Transfer Encoding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

You can send request in http 1.0 instead of 1.1  to avoid this or you can decode it easily (check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Example ) really easy to decode ,

Or use php-curl, it will automatically decode the response for you.